# Database: Splitting Tables

Tags: database, database-design

I've recently read alot about databases, redundancy, etc.

Now I'm building an users-table which will hold all informations
about the users registered at my system.

The users-table should hold: id(PK), username, password, email, and the address(street,
city, zipcode, country).

Should I split the address and create another table only holding the users-address,
like: id(PK), street, city, zipcode, country, user_id(FK)) ?
I even could split here the zipcode and country to new tables.

Does this make sense, especially the splitting of zipcode and country to a new table ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well I thought about some redundancy-aspects here.
Wouldn't it be better to store e.g. the country in a single table
instead of writing it over and over again in my users-table? -> redundancy

Comment: This is not the same as what you asked in the question. According to your question you are creating the redundancy anyway. You could have a list of countries and states and link to them in your user table and it's absolutely fine.

Comment: This is what I basically mean ... to split e.g. the country to a single table holding all countrys and then link them in my users-table with a foreign-key to the corresponding country.

Comment: It makes sense to have country, or state in their own tables and link to them. In that way you can provide the user with a select box to choose his country instead of writing it (which is prone to misspelling, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

For most cases the answer is no. Why have an extra join to find the address? And why have two tables with one-to-one relationship?

As other folks said, don't complicate your life unless you are sure about some performance gains.

Comment: Not just performance gains.  Also gains with regard to flexibility and future-proofing.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't see any added value on splitting these details into separated tables.

Even if you are not likely to use the address/zipcode very often, you can always select only the necessary fields using `SELECT username,email..` instead of `SELECT *..`

Answer (score 0):

You should do this based on a requirement, not because you can. So, either you should have a functional need (e.g., you want to store multiple addresses per user) or a technical issue that you want to solve (performance, security, etc.). To me, the latter sounds rather unlikely on such a straightforward table design, so with the information you are providing, I would suggest sticking with a single table.